# access_denied error in 3-legged oauth flow for sharepoint app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, onedrive-for-business

I have installed the app(tenant level) from Sharepoint store and the app gets installed successfully for every one in the organization.

While doing 3-legged authorization flow, after executing authorization url in the browser, it is redirecting to login page but then once the user(Global Admin) logs-in, instead of going to app trust page we got 'access_denied' error from the SharePoint server.

Is there any settings or permissions which prevents the user to trust the app on the fly ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: we are having Office365 Enterprise E4 license.